# android help activity page

Tags: android

I want to build a help page for my app so obviously it is gona be texty. Other than putting those texts inside my string.xml or in my layout xml, is there any other ways for me to do it? how do I include paragraphs in them? any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your help text into `strings.xml` file and use `\n\n` for line break as `@alex` suggested because in future if you want help text in different language then you can easily do this by adding different `strings.xml` file for different [localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

But if you still do not want to put help text into strings.xml then you can use

```
static final String helpText = "help text";
```

and set help text into `textView`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your text strings in `strings.xml`.
2. Reference them in your layout's XML.
3. Use `\n\n` to mark the beginning of a new paragraph.

Comment: Thank u! i shall try it then!